# If $X_n,\,n\geqslant 1$ are independent random variables, prove that $\mathbb{P}(\sup X_n<+\infty)=0$ or $1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X_n,\,n\geqslant 1$ be independent random variables defined on the same probability space. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(\sup X_n<+\infty)=0$ or $1$.

*Attempt.* Kologorov's $0-1$ law does not apply, since rv $\sup X_n$ is not $\mathcal{C}_{\infty}$ measurable, where $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}_{\infty}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots)$. On the other hand:
$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_nX_n<+\infty) = \lim_{m\to +\infty}\mathbb{P}(\sup_nX_n<m)=
\lim_{m\to +\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n<m ~\textrm{for all}~n)$$
$$=\lim_{m\to +\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n<m),$$
due to independence, but I cannot handle this double limit.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$supX_n <\infty$ iff $\lim \sup X_n <\infty$. And $(\lim \sup X_n <\infty)$ is  a tail event, so you can apply $0-1$ law.